# Should API fetching be frontend or backend?

Tags: python, flask

My website application is using React for the frontend, and I'm deciding between ExpressJS or Flask.py for the backend. Either way, I know React has API fetching functions but also the other backend-dedicated frameworks. My question is, conventionally, would API fetching logic be part of the frontend or backend?

Comment: I intend to use APIs in this application to get json data from another source to then be displayed on the client end. As this is exposed to the client, I can do it in React or use a backend framework for the API logic and then render it using react. To clarify, is it convention to put any API that the client side can see in the backend or frontend?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Say for example I wanted to have a list of cities and update the current weather conditions to the client by using an API from a news weather service. Because it's a component shown in the frontend, should the logic of the API be done in the frontend framework/library, or should it be in the backend and then rendered to the DOM.

Comment: @Nathanyc - Does my answer below not explain the decision process for you?  What is that missing?

Comment: I get it now. Sorry, I'm still new to this. Thanks for clearing it up for me!

Answer (score 12):

There are some conditions which require or prefer API fetching to be in the back-end:

1. When you need to use **security credentials** to access the API and you those credentials need to stay private.
2. When the API does not permit **cross origin access** so your front-end could not directly access it.
3. When you need to do some processing on the API results and you wish to **keep the processing algorithms a trade secret** (keep in mind that all processing done in the front-end is available for any coder to see).  There are no secrets in the front-end code.
4. When the front-end device may not have **appropriate resources** (CPU, memory, etc..) to process the API results.  This can particularly be the case with smaller dedicated devices.
5. When you don't want the front-end device to have to **expend the battery energy** to regularly access the API.  This might particularly be the case if you're regularly polling some API looking for changes.  In that case, you might want the back-end to do the polling and just let the front-end know when there is something to actually do.
6. When there are reasons to do some **centralized performance management** of your access to the API such as caching of results or request throttling.
7. When all front-end devices may not have **proper network access to the API** server.

If there are no compelling benefits to putting the API access in the back-end, then it may be more scalable (for your  server) to let the front-end do as much work as it can.

Comment: @nathanyc - Since it looks like you may be new here, if this answers your question, you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer and that will also earn you some reputation points here on stackoverflow for following the proper procedure.